# How to handle the categorical_column in parse_single_example function.

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

I am trying to use parse_single_example to process the TFRecordDataset file.
But It looks it can not handle the categorical_column in the Example proto.

For example:
In the example, there are 3 features. "a", "b", and "month". 
mouth is an int64 type feature, here I'd like to use parse this field and expand to a categorical signal directly.

I am not sure if parse_single_example support it or my method is totally wrong?

```
def _parse_function(example_proto):
    print(example_proto)
    features = {"a": tf.VarLenFeature(tf.float32),
                "b": tf.VarLenFeature(tf.float32),
                "month": tf.feature_column.categorical_column_with_identity(key='month', num_buckets=12),
                "label": tf.FixedLenFeature((), tf.float32, default_value=0.0)}
    parsed_features = tf.parse_single_example(example_proto, features)
    return tf.concat([tf.sparse_tensor_to_dense(parsed_features["a"]),
                     tf.sparse_tensor_to_dense(parsed_features["b"]),
                     parsed_features["month"]], 0),\
           tf.cast(parsed_features["close_pct"] + tf.convert_to_tensor(1.0, tf.float32), tf.int64)
```

https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/io/parse_single_example

https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/feature_column/categorical_column_with_identity

Answer (score 0):

Use tf.one_hot after parse the example.

```
return tf.concat([tf.sparse_tensor_to_dense(parsed_features["a"]),
                     tf.sparse_tensor_to_dense(parsed_features["b"]),
                     tf.one_hot(parsed_features["month"], categorical_size, axis=-1)], 0),\
       tf.cast(parsed_features["close_pct"] + tf.convert_to_tensor(1.0, tf.float32), tf.int64)
```